# Is this a functional syncing algorithm?

Tags: database, algorithm, synchronization

I'm working on a basic syncing algorithm for a user's notes. I've got most of it figured out, but before I start programming it, I want to run it by here to see if it makes sense. Usually I end up not realizing one huge important thing that someone else easily saw that I couldn't. Here's how it works:

I have a table in my database where I insert objects called `SyncOperation`. A `SyncOperation` is a sort of metadata on the nature of what every device needs to perform to be up to date. Say a user has 2 registered devices, `firstDevice` and `secondDevice`. `firstDevice` creates a new note and pushes it to the server. Now, a `SyncOperation` is created with the note's Id, operation type, and `processedDeviceList`. I create a `SyncOperation` with type "`NewNot`e", and I add the originating device ID to that `SyncOperation`'s `processedDeviceList`. So now `secondDevice` checks in to the server to see if it needs to make any updates. It makes a query to get all `SyncOperations` where secondDeviceId is not in the `processedDeviceList`. It finds out its type is `NewNote`, so it gets the new note and adds itself to the `processedDeviceList`. Now this device is in sync.

When I delete a note, I find the already created `SyncOperation` in the table with type "NewNote". I change the type to Delete, remove all devices from `processedDevicesList` except for the device that deleted the note. So now when new devices call in to see what they need to update, since their deviceId is not in the `processedList`, they'll have to process that `SyncOperation`, which tells their device to delete that respective note.

And that's generally how it'd work. Is my solution too complicated? Can it be simplified? Can anyone think of a situation where this wouldn't work? Will this be inefficient on a large scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds very complicated - the central database shouldn't be responsible for determining which devices have recieved which updates. Here's how I'd do it:

- The database keeps a table of `SyncOperations` for each change. Each `SyncOperation` is has a `change_id` numbered in ascending order (that is, `change_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.)
- Each device keeps a `current_change_id` number representing what change it last saw.
- When a device wants to update, it does `SELECT * FROM SyncOperations WHERE change_id > current_change_id`. This gets it the list of all changes it needs to be up-to-date. Apply each of them in chronological order.

This has the charming feature that, if you wanted to, you could initialise a new device simply by creating a new client with `current_change_id = 0`. Then it would pull in all updates.

---

Note that this won't really work if two users can be doing concurrent edits (which edit "wins"?). You can try and merge edits automatically, or you can raise a notification to the user. If you want some inspiration, look at the operation of the `git` version control system (or Mercurial, or CVS...) for conflicting edits.

Comment: Hmm this is an interesting method, which might just work. The thing is, which I failed to mention originally, is that SyncOperations include sending operations that change configuration of notes, such as font size and other preferences. These options are stored in the main row for each note, so a new device can ignore all "modification" sync operations and get the "NewNote" sync ops directly, which already have all the modification data. So the question is, how do I know when to delete sync ops from database? I'd have to somehow keep track of which devices have processed which sync ops, no?

Comment: The entire point of the above approach is that the **devices** are responsible for being up to date. The server simply makes all "sync ops" available in chronological order. It's up to the devices to get any "sync ops" they need.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at SyncML for ideas on how to handle sync operations (http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/affiliates/syncml/syncml_sync_protocol_v11_20020215.pdf). SyncML has been around for a while, and as a public standard, has had a fair amount of scrutiny and review. There are also open source implementations (Funambol comes to mind) that can also provide some coding clues. You don't have to use the whole spec, but reading it may give you a few "ahah" moments about syncing data - I know it helped to think through what needs to be done.

Mark

P.S. A later version of the protocol - http://www.openmobilealliance.org/technical/release_program/docs/DS/V1_2_1-20070810-A/OMA-TS-DS_Protocol-V1_2_1-20070810-A.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the basic idea of keeping track of operations in a database elsewhere, so I dare say it can be made to work. You may wish to think about what should happen if different devices are in use at much the same time, and end up submitting conflicting changes - e.g. two different attempts to edit the same note. This may surface as a change to the user interface, to allow them to intervene to resolve such conflicts manually.